# null pointer exception with alertdailog

Tags: android, android-dialog

i searched on google, but didn't get something positive. i dont know why i am getting a null pointer exception  on alert dailog.create()

I am creating a dailog on click of a button
that dailog has a listview and a button in linearlayout

```
            viewReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    //created listMap
                    final String value[]=getKArrayFromMap(listMap);
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getParent()).create();
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getParent());
                    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    Button ok=new Button(getParent());

                    final ListView lv = new ListView(getParent());
                    // simple_list_item_checked
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getParent(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, value);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    linearLayout.addView(lv);
                    linearLayout.addView(ok);
                    alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);

                    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            // some work
                    }



                            );
                    alertDialog.show();


                }
            });
```

Got null pointer exception at:

```
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at com.cloudchowk.his.doctor.laboratory.BindDetailsActivity$BackGroundProcess$6.onClick(BindDetailsActivity.java:794)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-27 11:37:37.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line no 794:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getParent()).create();
```

Comment: show full logcat of this exception

Comment: use `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
     classname.this);'

Comment: what is the problem with getParent()

Comment: @damian updated the log in the ques

Comment: what kind of AlertDialog are you trying to create? With selection or ?

Comment: to create an alert dailog with checkboxes and a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this by:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        yourActivity.this).create();
```

You have to change **YourActivity.this** at where you have use **getParent()**;

Comment: got nullpointer exception exception at new Linearlayout(getParent())

Comment: what is the problem with getParent()

Comment: getParent() used at that time when you are calling child activity from parent activity in TabGroup Activity.

Comment: i am using almost same code in other activity and it is working good, there is only one difference, it does not have button instead has editText, but i dont think it makes any dissference

Comment: yes, both are extends of activity, both works on click of a button

Comment: But its wrong to use getParent() for Activity.... you can use getApplicationContext() or YourActivity.this

Comment: i have used getParent() almost on all dailogs in my app, a large no of times, but problemm occur this time only

Comment: should i change all of them ( in case of dialogs) to save future crashes, or it can work its way if its working now..

Comment: Right now if its working good then as you wish ...But sometimes it might be harmful as you have seen in this...

Answer (score 0):

Do this way may help you

```
viewReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                //created listMap
                final String value[]=getKArrayFromMap(listMap);
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this).create();
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                Button ok=new Button(MainActivity.this);

                final ListView lv = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
                // simple_list_item_checked
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, value);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                linearLayout.addView(lv);
                linearLayout.addView(ok);
                alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // some work
                }



                        );
                alertDialog.show();


            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: got nullpointer exception exception at new Linearlayout(getParent())

Comment: what is the problem with getParent()

Comment: getParent() used at that time when you are calling child activity from parent activity in TabGroup Activity.......

Answer (score 0):

i have Done it just past this code,

```
okay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this).create();
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(
                    getApplicationContext());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            Button ok = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            final ListView lv = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                    value);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            linearLayout.addView(lv);
            linearLayout.addView(ok);
            alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "asdhfkja is done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

or Just change

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    YOUR_ACTIVITY.this).create();
```

and replace all `getParent()` with `getApplicationContect()`